# Error when I want to disable ssl certificate verification in axios in react project

Tags: reactjs, ssl, https, axios, verification

I installed TLS on a server on the Azure side and I cannot log in to the react project due to TLS. I get the net::ERR_CERT_AUTHORITY_INVALID error in the console. Therefore, I add the following code to disable SSL certificate verification on the Axios side, then I get another error.

const https = require('https')

const agent = new https.Agent({
rejectUnauthorized: false,
requestCert: false,
agent: false,
})

---

2. Issue

BREAKING CHANGE: webpack < 5 used to include polyfills for node.js core modules by default.
This is no longer the case. Verify if you need this module and configure a polyfill for it.

If you want to include a polyfill, you need to:
- add a fallback 'resolve.fallback: { "https": require.resolve("https-browserify") }'
- install 'https-browserify'
If you don't want to include a polyfill, you can use an empty module like this:
resolve.fallback: { "https": false }

---

What should be the solution?

Comment: Why the additional options after `rejectUnauthorized: false`?

Comment: I added HTTPS=true to the .env file and the problem was solved.

Comment: I tried different solutions and this one solved my problem. I shared it because I thought it would be useful. What's interesting?

Comment: Okay, I added it as an answer.

Comment: Cool. Don't forget to accept your answer unless somebody posts a better one. All that is left otherwise is to remove the unneeded comments by deleting your comments. You can try flagging this comment to get it removed by a mod.

Answer (score 2):

I added HTTPS=true to the .env file and the problem was solved.